# PHP API TO CREATE JSON FILE USING MYSQL DATABASE

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to write a PHP API through I can create JSON file by using MySQL.

Suppose I have a table "A" and I have 2 columns `FILENAME` and `FILETYPE` with 10 rows inserted.

I have to write a PHP code which will create a JSON file and take the data from table A (i.e. 10 rows) and print the value in a valid JSON format into JSON file.

Comment: please turn off caps lock while typing

Comment: the question format is just bad. You aren't showing any code, you are asking for the ppl here to do all the work for you... take a look at the `json_encode()` function

Comment: ARE MAD WHILE TYPING YOUR QUESTION?

Comment: sorry for the caps lock, i have no idea how to start with it. i have created a media player by using html5, jquery and json. The json entry is done by user. now i want to take the values from the mysql using php

Answer (score 0):

Just select the data, and then do:

```
file_put_contents('your/json/file.x',json_encode($theData));
```

[read the docs](http://www.php.net/json_encode) to see what the output will be.
If you need some more bells and whistles, there is [a Zend_Json object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.html), among others (just google for "PHP JSON class"), and have a look at the results

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Hope this will be helpful for me.

Comment: If the data has to be sent to the client, don't write it to a file BTW, just echo the json string: `echo json_encode($theData);`, and it'll be sent as the response to your AJAX call.

Comment: can you suggest me some link then it will be very helpful for me. thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, apart from the 2 links I already supplied, here's [a link to an example using jQuery, PHP and JSON encoded data](http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/), just google _PHP Json AJAX jQuery tutorials_ or something, it honestly isn't that hard